# Could not parse the remainder: '{{comment.post}}=={{blog.post}}' from '{{comment.post}}=={{blog.post}}'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am making a blog website and I have to add comments to my post for that I have to check which post the comment is associated with and I am writing this line

```
{% if {{comment.post}}=={{blog.post}} %}
```

I know this line won't work because {%%} and {{}} cannot be used in the same line so does anyone has a solution for this.

Comment: `{% if comment.post==blog.post %}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% if comment.post == blog.post %}
…
{% endif %}
```

this will work well

Answer (score 1):

In a template tag, you do not use the double curly brackets, but just the variables:

```
{% if comment.post == blog.post %}
    …
{% endif %}
```

That being said, please do *not* filter in a template. Business logic belongs to the models or views. If you use relations, like a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey), or a [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField), then Django adds managers to the corresponding models. This also means it fetches the *related* comments by a query to the database. Especially if the number of comments will increase, eventually filtering in the template will no longer be feasible.